# How I can add PHP code to a code snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

When I asked a question on SO, other users asked me to add a live demo. But my code contains a part in PHP and I can't see a method to add code other than HTML, CSS and JS in a code snippet.

Is it possible to add a demonstration of any other languages in a code snippet? If so, how?

Comment: No bro, it will not support anything other than HTML, CSS and JS :)

Comment: [as i said before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285566/250962), i think they might be referring to making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). otherwise there are [third](https://repl.it/) [party](http://sqlfiddle.com/) sites not affiliated with Stack Exchange where you can put your code up as demos.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to use the snippet feature to add code to your question. It currently only supports HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Try the "code sample" formatting button instead:

[image]

See also: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: i just want show live demo.not just to add code

Comment: @dreamhunter No way to do that on SO for PHP at the moment, then, sorry.

Comment: it's ok,i just wish to know  is there any languages support other than css,js or html. now i'm clear about that

Answer (score 3):

Code snippets are presently aimed for HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  You wouldn't be able to use it with PHP at this moment in time.  In your context I wouldn't even advise you to use it since it would only serve to confuse anyone who would want to run your code, with them thinking in error that it's all self-contained in the snippet.

I would recommend that you be sure that you narrow down the code that actually is both needed in the question *and* reproduces the exact issue you have.  Adding code can be important, but be sure that the code you add to your question *actually* matters.

Answer (score 3):

Code snippets are for self-contained examples of client side code.

PHP code isn't client side and thus it would make no sense in the context of the code snippet feature to add support for it.

Comment: :then whynot all other client side codes are not supported / built in code snippet?

Comment: @dreamhunter Its currently only for html/css/js, but I suppose they could add support for more code. But the idea of snippets are that they're self contained and runnable, so having server side code on there would not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Stijn I reworded it a bit. Wasn't intended that way, but I can see how it could come off as a little rude.